# Can i boot a password for my Ubuntu while booting

Tags: boot, 13.04, password

I saw it on my friend's laptop when the laptop is booting and this screen below appears ,
 the device doesn't complete booting until he put a password

can any one help me if he knows the way ?
[image]

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to do what @bodhi.zazen answered http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/09/04/full-disk-encryption-and-lvm-configuration-in-ubuntus-graphical-installer/

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-install and perform full disk encryption (LUKS). You will then be prompted to enter a password when you boot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a bios or grub password

Comment: what is grub password ?

Comment: you can set a password before that screen appears, does not protect any data from a live cd/usb though; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

Answer (score 1):

That thing needs Full Encryption enabled when u install Ubuntu...It can be done only at install..If you want it, reinstall Ubuntu... Though it has its own disadvantages in backups or restoring etc...